Path-based Routing with HAProxy Ingress in Kubernetes Not Working
I'm a beginner trying to set up path-based routing in Kubernetes using the HAProxy Ingress controller. The Ingress works when I use / as the path, but it fails when I try to use a path like /test. Below is my Ingress configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-server-ingress
  namespace: web
spec:
  ingressClassName: haproxy
  rules:
  - host: test.home
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-server-service
            port:
              number: 5000

this is my complete config:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: web
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-server
  namespace: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpd
        image: httpd:2.4.53-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-server-service
  namespace: web
spec:
  selector:
    app: web
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-server-ingress
  namespace: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpd
        image: httpd:2.4.53-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-server-service
  namespace: web
spec:
  selector:
    app: web
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-server-ingress
  namespace: web
spec:
  ingressClassName: haproxy
  rules:
  - host: test.home
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-server-service
            port:
              number: 5000

and this is the configuration for my ingress controller:
controller:
  ingressClassResource:
    enabled: true
  kind: DaemonSet
  daemonset:
    useHostPort: false
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer

I tried reinstalling everything from scratch and testing with different paths. I noticed that when I specify the correct path (e.g., /test), I get an error message saying the resource was not found. However, when I specify a path that does not exist, such as /nonexistent, I get a 404 Not Found error. This suggests that the routing might not be configured correctly for the /test path.

The issue arises because the path is forwarded to the backend by default. For example, in your configuration, the service was web-server-service. However, the Ingress forwarded the path as test.home/test, which caused your backend to become overwhelmed as it had no configuration to handle such paths. As a result, there was no resource available to process the request.
Solution:
I found the solution myself. You can resolve this issue by adding the following annotation to your Ingress resource:
annotations:
  haproxy-ingress.github.io/rewrite-target: /

This annotation rewrites the path so that the backend receives the request in a normalized way, such as simply web-server-service, instead of forwarding the original path (e.g., test.home/test). This adjustment ensures that the backend can properly handle the requests without requiring specific configurations for unexpected paths.
